# Vanilla Javascript - End Game When Player Reaches a Certain Score

Tags: javascript

I followed a tutorial to make a Rock, Paper, Scissors game and now I want to take it a step further to add a message / end the game when either the player or the computer reaches a score of 10. I'm having trouble figuring out what I need to do.

```
  let user = ["Player", "Computer"];
  let pScore = 0;
  let cScore = 0;
  let gameIsOver = false;
  
  // Some other functions in here...

  // End Game
  if (pScore === 10) {
    isGameOver = true;
    winner.textContent = `${user[0]} Wins the Game!`;
    return;
  } else if (cScore === 10) {
    isGameOver = true;
    winner.textContent = `${user[1]} Wins the Game!`;
    return;
  } else {
    isGameOver = false;
  }

  // Some other functions here...
```

Comment: `else` isn't needed when returning inside an if block.

Comment: `return` can only occur within a function. Also, there should be at least a loop somewhere. This piece of code is not going to be enough for us to help you out.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Thanks! I'm still learning all this stuff.

Comment: @trincot - I tried to include my full code, but it was too long. :( Maybe I can add another snippet here...

Comment: Here's a link to a codepen instead because the code is still too long. [link](https://codepen.io/redliz5808/pen/LYZGJQW)

Comment: The question should have all necessary information. As the CSS is not relevant to your question, you can leave already that out. Same for (updating) the images... etc There are enough ways to reduce your code and put it inside the question, preferably as a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the conditions every time the score changes. To do that, put your if-statements in a separate function and call it from the function which is triggered when someone scores. I create small functions because, in my opinion, it's the best practice, but not necessary for such a small operation.

```
let pScore = 0;
let cScore = 0;

let user = ["Player", "Computer"];


let isGameOver = (score) => {
  if (pScore === 10 || cScore === 10) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function gameOver() {
  let winner = pScore === 10 ? user[0] : user[1];
  console.log(winner);
}

function theFunctionThatChangesTheScores() {
  // after the code that changes the score
  if ( isGameOver() ) {
    // you can code in this block, but ideally.
    // create another function and call it:
    return gameOver();
  }
  return console.log("game is still on");
}

theFunctionThatChangesTheScores();
```